# Using simplexml on Android to convert an xml string to an object gives ParseError (AttributePrefixUnbound)

Tags: android, xml, simple-framework

I have an XML string:

```
<Transactions>
  <TaskFormInstance TransactionID="8230">
    <uuid>df534b09-30fc-fe81-e411-a2862ef53439</uuid>
    <taskId>272</taskId>
    <status>3-COLLECTED</status>
    <element>
      <uuid>a99afff5-0927-21b7-e411-a286183d17bb</uuid>
      <elementNo>1</elementNo>
      <label>label1</label>
      <type>Integer</type>
      <dependsOn>0</dependsOn>
      <minimumValue>0</minimumValue>
      <maximumValue>100</maximumValue>
      <minimumCharacters xsi:nil="true"/>
      <maximumCharacters xsi:nil="true"/>
    </element>
    <element>
      <uuid>a99afff5-0927-21b7-e411-a2864e4515bb</uuid>
      <elementNo>2</elementNo>
      <label>label2</label>
      <type>Integer</type>
      <dependsOn>0</dependsOn>
      <minimumValue>0</minimumValue>
      <maximumValue>50</maximumValue>
      <minimumCharacters xsi:nil="true"/>
      <maximumCharacters xsi:nil="true"/>
    </element>
  </TaskFormInstance>
</Transactions>
```

I am using simplexml to convert it to a Java object.

```
Serializer serializer = new Persister();
Reader reader = new StringReader(xml);
TaskFormTransactionListTransportBean taskFormTransactionListTransportBean = serializer.read(TaskFormTransactionListTransportBean.class, reader, false);
```

Here are my beans it converts to:

```
    @Root(name="Transactions")
    public class TaskFormTransactionListTransportBean {

    @ElementList(inline = true, required = false)
    private ArrayList<TaskFormTransportBean> taskFormTransportBeans;

    public TaskFormTransactionListTransportBean() {
        taskFormTransportBeans = new ArrayList<TaskFormTransportBean>();
    }

    public ArrayList<TaskFormTransportBean> getTaskFormTransportBeans() {
        return taskFormTransportBeans;
    }

    public void setTaskTransactions(ArrayList<TaskFormTransportBean> taskFormTransportBeans) {
        this.taskFormTransportBeans = taskFormTransportBeans;
    }
```

}

and:

```
@Root(name="TaskFormInstance")
public class TaskFormTransportBean {

    @Attribute(name="TransactionID")
    private String transactionId;

    @Element(name="uuid",required=true)
    private String uuid;

    @Element(name="status",required=false)
    private String status;

    @Element(name="name",required=false)
    private String name;

    @Element(name="taskFormNumber",required=false)
    private String taskFormNumber;

    @ElementList(inline = true, required = false)
    private ArrayList<ElementTransportBean> elements;

    public String getTransactionId() {
        return transactionId;
    }

    public void setTransactionId(String transactionId) {
        this.transactionId = transactionId;
    }

    public String getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

    public void setUuid(String uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getTaskFormNumber() {
        return taskFormNumber;
    }

    public void setTaskFormNumber(String taskFormNumber) {
        this.taskFormNumber = taskFormNumber;
    }

    public ArrayList<ElementTransportBean> getElements() {
        return elements;
    }

    public void setElements(ArrayList<ElementTransportBean> elements) {
        this.elements = elements;
    }

}
```

and:

```
@Root(name="element")
public class ElementTransportBean {

    @Element(name="uuid",required=true)
    private String uuid;

    @Element(name="value",required=false)
    private String value;

    @Element(name="elementNo",required=true)
    private String elementNo;

    @Element(name="dependsOn",required=false)
    private String dependsOn;

    @Element(name="label",required=true)
    private String label;

    @Element(name="type",required=true)
    private String type;

    @Element(name="minimumValue",required=false)
    private String minValue;

    @Element(name="maximumValue",required=false)
    private String maxValue;

    @Element(name="minimumCharacters",required=false)
    private String minNoOfChars;

    @Element(name="maximumCharacters",required=false)
    private String maxNoOfChars;

    public String getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

    public void setUuid(String uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getElementNo() {
        return elementNo;
    }

    public void setElementNo(String elementNo) {
        this.elementNo = elementNo;
    }

    public String getDependsOn() {
        return dependsOn;
    }

    public void setDependsOn(String dependsOn) {
        this.dependsOn = dependsOn;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getMinValue() {
        return minValue;
    }

    public void setMinValue(String minValue) {
        this.minValue = minValue;
    }

    public String getMaxValue() {
        return maxValue;
    }

    public void setMaxValue(String maxValue) {
        this.maxValue = maxValue;
    }

    public String getMinNoOfChars() {
        return minNoOfChars;
    }

    public void setMinNoOfChars(String minNoOfChars) {
        this.minNoOfChars = minNoOfChars;
    }

    public String getMaxNoOfChars() {
        return maxNoOfChars;
    }

    public void setMaxNoOfChars(String maxNoOfChars) {
        this.maxNoOfChars = maxNoOfChars;
    }

}
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[15,42]
Message: http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xml-names-19990114#AttributePrefixUnbound?minimumCharacters&xsi:nil&xsi
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:598)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLEventReaderImpl.nextEvent(XMLEventReaderImpl.java:83)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader.read(StreamReader.java:110)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader.next(StreamReader.java:94)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.stream.NodeReader.readElement(NodeReader.java:121)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.stream.InputElement.getNext(InputElement.java:216)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readElements(Composite.java:447)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.access$400(Composite.java:59)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite$Builder.read(Composite.java:1383)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:201)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:148)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Traverser.read(Traverser.java:92)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.CompositeInlineList.read(CompositeInlineList.java:190)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.CompositeInlineList.read(CompositeInlineList.java:167)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.CompositeInlineList.read(CompositeInlineList.java:124)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readVariable(Composite.java:623)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readInstance(Composite.java:573)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readUnion(Composite.java:549)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readElement(Composite.java:532)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readElements(Composite.java:445)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.access$400(Composite.java:59)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite$Builder.read(Composite.java:1383)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:201)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:148)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Traverser.read(Traverser.java:92)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.CompositeInlineList.read(CompositeInlineList.java:190)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.CompositeInlineList.read(CompositeInlineList.java:167)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.CompositeInlineList.read(CompositeInlineList.java:144)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readVariable(Composite.java:619)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readInstance(Composite.java:573)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readUnion(Composite.java:549)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readElement(Composite.java:532)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readElements(Composite.java:445)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.access$400(Composite.java:59)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite$Builder.read(Composite.java:1383)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:201)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:148)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Traverser.read(Traverser.java:92)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:625)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:606)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:584)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:562)
    at za.co.company.androidsoap.poc.AndroidSoapTest.getTaskFormInserts(AndroidSoapTest.java:323)
    at za.co.company.androidsoap.poc.AndroidSoapTest.main(AndroidSoapTest.java:76)
za.co.company.androidsoap.poc.TransportException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[15,42]
Message: http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xml-names-19990114#AttributePrefixUnbound?minimumCharacters&xsi:nil&xsi
    at za.co.company.androidsoap.poc.AndroidSoapTest.getTaskFormInserts(AndroidSoapTest.java:333)
    at za.co.company.androidsoap.poc.AndroidSoapTest.main(AndroidSoapTest.java:76)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[15,42]
Message: http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xml-names-19990114#AttributePrefixUnbound?minimumCharacters&xsi:nil&xsi
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:598)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLEventReaderImpl.nextEvent(XMLEventReaderImpl.java:83)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader.read(StreamReader.java:110)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader.next(StreamReader.java:94)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.stream.NodeReader.readElement(NodeReader.java:121)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.stream.InputElement.getNext(InputElement.java:216)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readElements(Composite.java:447)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.access$400(Composite.java:59)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite$Builder.read(Composite.java:1383)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:201)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:148)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Traverser.read(Traverser.java:92)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.CompositeInlineList.read(CompositeInlineList.java:190)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.CompositeInlineList.read(CompositeInlineList.java:167)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.CompositeInlineList.read(CompositeInlineList.java:124)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readVariable(Composite.java:623)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readInstance(Composite.java:573)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readUnion(Composite.java:549)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readElement(Composite.java:532)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readElements(Composite.java:445)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.access$400(Composite.java:59)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite$Builder.read(Composite.java:1383)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:201)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:148)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Traverser.read(Traverser.java:92)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.CompositeInlineList.read(CompositeInlineList.java:190)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.CompositeInlineList.read(CompositeInlineList.java:167)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.CompositeInlineList.read(CompositeInlineList.java:144)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readVariable(Composite.java:619)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readInstance(Composite.java:573)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readUnion(Composite.java:549)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readElement(Composite.java:532)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readElements(Composite.java:445)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.access$400(Composite.java:59)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite$Builder.read(Composite.java:1383)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:201)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:148)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Traverser.read(Traverser.java:92)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:625)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:606)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:584)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:562)
    at za.co.company.androidsoap.poc.AndroidSoapTest.getTaskFormInserts(AndroidSoapTest.java:323)
    ... 1 more
```

If I remove the following lines from the xml string, it works fine:

```
<minimumCharacters xsi:nil="true"/>
<maximumCharacters xsi:nil="true"/>
```

How do I get simplexml to parse the xml properly if I leave those lines in which include the "xsi:nil" attributes?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. The XML being supplied is not really correct.

I added the name space to the first element:

```
<Transactions xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 ...
</Transactions>
```

Simplexml now parses it without the exception.

I will just ask the for the xml being generated to be done properly.